# Preview in auctex on debian stable works in dvi mode, but fails on pdf mode

Tags: pdf, auctex, preview, dvi, ghostscript

My `auctex` renders preview images on my debian stable system (6.0.6) if I set it to `dvi` mode, but it fails if I set `auctex` to `pdf` mode.

[image: auctex renders preview images on my debian stable system]
[image: auctex fails if i set it to pdf mode]

I assume there is either a mistake in my `emacs` configuration or a permanent bug in the `ghostscript` package.

I need help to isolate the bug step by step. Additionally I would be glad, if someone with the same software could help me out with his configuration.

Perhaps it will help, if I can upgrade the `ghostscript` package, but I have no idea how to do this as I found no backport yet.

My complete [emacs configuration is available on github](https://github.com/jonasstein/emacs-config).

```
$ ghostscript --version
8.71
$ emacs-snapshot --version
GNU Emacs 24.2.50.1
$ pdftex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
```

Comment: Direct PDF output does not use GhostScript, nor does it produce `.dvi` files (which are needed by `preview`). I'm therefore wondering if this can possibly work!

Comment: If PDF output denies preview, preview should ignore the [x] Generate PDF checkbox and just do its job with the `.dvi` settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct PDF output does not use GhostScript, nor does it produce `.dvi` files (which are needed by preview). Thus this is probably a bug in AUCTeX: the options should not allow 'Create a PDF' with direct PDF output.